# How do I find the value of an index in an ndarray and convert to pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an `ndarray` created by a cKDTree, like this:

```
idx = array([[2941, 4837, 3593],
             [ 323, 3209, 3649]])
```

and I'd like to use that to create a pandas `DataFrame` using those as indices to another data frame that has some other symbols, for example:

```
2941, A
4837, B
3593, C
323,  D
3209, E
3649, F
```

And, using something like `gdf = pd.DataFrame(idx)` I'd like to have a `DataFrame`

```
    idx_0   idx_1   idx_2
0       A       B       C
1       D       E       F
```

instead of

```
    idx_0   idx_1   idx_2
0    2941    4837    3593
1     323    3209    3649
```

How do I do that with a multidimensional array? `df.loc[idx]` won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with `apply` for all columns of `DataFrame`:

```
s = df.set_index('a')['b']
print (s)
a
2941    A
4837    B
3593    C
323     D
3209    E
3649    F
Name: b, dtype: object

idx = np.array([[2941, 4837, 3593],
             [ 323, 3209, 3649]])

gdf = pd.DataFrame(idx).apply(lambda x: x.map(s))
print (gdf)
   0  1  2
0  A  B  C
1  D  E  F
```

Comment: For mapping, a `dict` would be a whole lot better. Then just use map directly. @jezrael.

Comment: @Vishnudev - Yes, it depends, I think series is better for returned error if duplicated values in first column, if convert to dict, no error (so not idea if something wrong with data). so generally in my opinion is better map by Series, only if always unique index (first column here), then map by dict is also good.

Comment: I speculated that index given by OP is unique. Makes sense. @jezrael

Comment: @Vishnudev - Yop, only explain why I use `map` by `Series`, but if values are unique, then dict is good solution too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
lookup = dict(zip(df[0], df[1]))
result = pd.DataFrame(idx).applymap(lookup.get)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
     0   1   2
0    A   B   C
1    D   E   F
```

Assuming `df` is:

```
      0    1
0  2941    A
1  4837    B
2  3593    C
3   323    D
4  3209    E
5  3649    F
```

As an alternative, given that `idx` is a numpy array, you could map using  [numpy.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), and then build the DataFrame:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(np.vectorize(lookup.get)(idx))
```